# Creating a sample preview document

Tags: latex, tex

Is it possible to create a sample preview document easily using final document by replacing, hiding or replacing some of the pages by blank pages?

What I want to do is to create a preview document (very similar to the way google books or amazon show few pages of the entire book and hide many pages). Is this possible to generate such a document using some tricks, commands in latex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pagesel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) allows you to select only certain pages to be output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[-4,3,even,7-8]{pagesel}% Keep only pages 2, 4, 8
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,multido}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \makebox[0pt]{%
      \raisebox{-.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \resizebox{.8\paperwidth}{.8\paperheight}{\thepage}}}}}
\pagestyle{empty}% No headers/footers
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{10}{\mbox{}\clearpage}% Create 10 pages
\end{document}
```

Using blank pages might be awkward from the end-user's perspective.